# how to merge 2 database on one datagridview c#

Tags: c#, sql

In one form I have 2 DGV and 2 Database !, one to view transaction and one to view the header detail (im only can display one transaction) but I cant display other one to display header detail

How to merge a data from 2 Primary Key or ID from different database into a DataGridView inside one View Form ?

This is my code :

```
    public HistoryTransaction()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HistoryTransaction_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this is to get data from database
        dataSource = con.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TrHeaderTransaction");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;

        dataSource2 = con.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TrDetailTransaction");
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dataSource2;

        //to select data into dataTable
        DataTable obj = con.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TrHeaderTransaction");
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            transBox.Items.Add(obj.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        }
        transBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void CloseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do a join at the database:

```
SELECT * FROM TrHeaderTransaction, TrDetailTransaction 
  WHERE TrHeaderTransaction.ID = TrDetailTransaction.HeaderID
```

Of course, not knowing the names of your fields, I can't give the exact SQL.

There is also the [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) syntax you can use.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand from your requirement is, you're either looking for database solution which is as follows:

```
enter code here

SELECT h.*,d.* FROM TrHeaderTransaction h, TrDetailTransaction d
 WHERE h.TrHeaderTransaction.ID = d.TrDetailTransaction.ID and 
 h.TrHeaderTransaction.SID = d.TrDetailTransaction.ID

 or 

 Alternatively you can do the same using datatables at the front end;
```